# Oven Media Engine with RTMP Protocol

Tags: rtmp

I was trying to work with Oven Media Engine with RTMP protocol.. I can see in the configuration page of RTMP, they have provided code. But when i copy the same code and add in the Server.xml which is located in  /usr/share/ovenmediaengine/conf/, OME service is not starting.

Please let me know when can i add those code in Server.xml

RTMP Code:
https://airensoft.gitbook.io/ovenmediaengine/live-source/rtmp#rtmp-live-stream

Original Code:
https://airensoft.gitbook.io/ovenmediaengine/configuration#configuration-example

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us your entire Server.xml and which log (OvenMediaEngine.log) is output when you run ovenmediaengine. You can also quickly get answers by posting your OME questions on Github (https://github.com/AirenSoft/OvenMediaEngine/issues). Their Github is very active.